# trouble installing ubuntu 12.10 on asus windows 8 ultrabook

Tags: installation, dual-boot, virtualbox, asus

since ubuntu insists on only distributing the OS with unity (when I prefer gnome) I decided that since the company i work for got us new laptops, I was going to install backtrack.
However it turns out I had to install an old version of backtrack and then upgrade to a newer version, too much fiddling for my liking.

eventually I decided to install ubuntu since I had the image for 12.10 in 64bit. my problem is that throughout the day yesterday I've found that there are settings on he machine that had to be changed for me to install ubuntu on this Asus Ultrabook, but after turning off fast startup and the other 'FAST' setting in the BIOS, I still get only a black screen after selecting either running ubuntu from my live flash drive or selecting the install option.

can somebody pleeeeease help me, windows 8 is worse than windows 7 and the last windows OS I could bare with was XP, I cannot run ubuntu in a vm (VirtualBox by Oracle) on windows 8 because of some of the restrictions microsoft put in windows since vista

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Start up Windows 8, but don't log in
2. Click the power button, then Restart, while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>
3. Click Advanced Options
4. Click UEFI Firmware Settings
5. Wait for your computer to restart into BIOS
6. Find the Secure Boot Option and disable it from there

It is important you boot into BIOS using this method because otherwise Windows 8 will not shut off completely and you will corrupt it's installation when you install Ubuntu. Once you have done this, install Ubuntu normally. Chances are, it will not be bootable (you will go straight into Windows if you are dual-booting). If not, you are done installing Ubuntu and should not go beyond this point. If this happens, turn Windows off using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Restart trick and choosing to Power Off. Then, follow these instructions:

1. Boot into your LiveCD
2. Connect to a WiFi connection point
3. Open up Terminal by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
4. Run the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot-repair && sudo boot-repair`
5. Choose the Recommended Repair
6. Follow the instructions, restarting when done
7. Profit! You should now have a bootable setup with Ubuntu installed.

Comment: sounds promising, going to mosque quickly, will try it when I get back, thanks